# Asset has a child category but only displays the parent on templates

Tags: assets, category, children

I have an asset volume that has a category field. The category field has no max level so I can have parent/child categories.
If I set a child category to the asset in /admin then all is well, but when I go to display the asset and category then I only get the top level (parent) category and not the child category set in /admin.

Similar thing happens if I use the `group` filter, the groups are only the top level category titles.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your Twig template that's generating the incorrect output.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that setting a child category also sets it's parents categories too (top level being first, and selected child category is last).

Able to get the category with `{{ asset.categoryField.all()|last.title }}`